# I could not understand what does this program does, it is a recursive one

Tags: c, arrays, function, recursion

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

#define SIZE 10 

int whatIsThis(const int b[], size_t p);

int main(void) {
    int x;
    int a[SIZE] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

    x = whatIsThis(a, SIZE);

    printf("result is %d\n", x);

    _sleep(1000 * 100);
}

int whatIsThis(const int b[], size_t p) {
    if (1 == p) {
        return b[0];
    } else {
        return b[p - 1] + whatIsThis(b, p - 1);
    }
}
```

Sorry to ask this question but I am almost beginner in C programming and I could not understand the logic of this program, especially `return b[p-1]+ whatIsThis(b,p-1);`.  What is the logic of this?

Comment: High time to start using a debugger.\

Comment: Well, how about you write down on paper what's happening? This is surely some kind of homework to teach you recursion, so: either run the program and debug, or "be the debugger".

Comment: Format the code. I think you will understand the code yourself. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is this?

It is a function with undefined behavior.:)

When the second argument is equal to 0 the function tries to access memory in the position `p - 1` that in general as the type `size_t` is an unsigned type is converted to the maximum value that can be stored in an object of type `size_t`.

Moreover as inside the function there is used the addition operation then there can be overflow for two big numbers. Thus the return type of the function should be some other larger integer type.

So let's rewrite the function that to remove these drawbacks. The logic will be the same.

```
long long int whatIsThis( const int a[], size_t n ) 
{
    return n == 0 ? 0 : a[n-1] + whatIsThis( a, n - 1 );
}
```

Or without using the ternary (conditional) operator the function will look like

```
long long int whatIsThis( const int a[], size_t n ) 
{
    if ( n == 0 ) 
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else 
    {
        return a[n-1] + whatIsThis( a, n - 1 );
    }
}
```

Now let-s consider how the function works. If you have an array like this

```
int a[10] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
```

You can imagine it the following way (though this code will not be compiled)

```
int a[10] = { { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 }, 10 };
```

or like this

```
int a[10] = { a1[9], 10 };
```

where a1[9] is an array of 9 elements

```
int a1[9] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9  };
```

In turn the array a1 can be imagined like

```
int a1[9] = { a2[8], 9 };
```

where a2 is

```
int a2[8] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8  };
```

and so on that at last we will get

```
int a8[2] = { a9[1], 2 };
```

where a9 is

```
int a9[1] = { 1 };
```

So what does the function do?

For the array `a` that was imagined like

```
int a[10] = { { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 }, 10 };
```

or like

```
int a[10] = { a1[9], 10 };
```

the function adds `a1[9] + 10`

In turn for the array `a1` that is imagined like

```
int a1[9] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 }, 9  };
```

or like

```
int a1[9] = { a2[8], 9 };
```

the function calculates `a2[8] + 9`

If to substitute `a1[9]` in the expression `a1[9] + 10` with `a2[8] + 9` then we will get `a2[8] + 9 + 10` and so on.

So the function calculates the sum of the elements of the array.

Answer (score 6):

In order to understand code, you must read it carefully. The code posted was badly presented, which makes it hard to read, even for savvy programmers.  First indent and space the program the way I did it in my edit.

The function `whatIsThis()` first tests if its second argument `p` has the value `1`, with a silly inverted syntax `(1 == p)` in a lame attempt to detect a potentially mistyped `==` operator: `1 = p` would be a syntax error, whereas `p = 1` would be syntactically correct but not a test on `p`.

The name of the second argument is misleading, it is the number of elements in `b`. As such, it would be more readable to name it `n`, `len`, `count`... but not `p` which is classically used for pointers.

If this size is 1, the function returns the value of the first element of the array.

If not, it returns the sum of the last element and the result of a call to itself for the same array and one less element.

Therefore the function computes the sum of the elements of the array.

Note that this function is bogus: it cannot handle a `0` value for `p` and invokes undefined behavior. A simpler and safer version would be:

```
int whatIsThis(const int b[], size_t n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return b[n - 1] + whatIsThis(b, n - 1);
    }
}
```

Or alternatively:

```
int whatIsThis(const int b[], size_t n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return b[0] + whatIsThis(b + 1, n - 1);
    }
}
```

Of course a recursive approach for such a simple task is risky as it may recurse very deep into the stack and invoke undefined behavior for moderately large arrays.  The compiler cannot always optimize the recursion out, especially when it is not tail recursion, and this typically isn't.

Comment: @Dr.Haimovitz huh? What do you mean? The answer is correct and complete. It even goes beyond what was asked and points out the shortcomings of the function and suggests an improvement. What do you mean by "Defently not the sum of the array." Please elaborate because as shown in the answer, it is *definitely* the sum of the elements in the array.

Comment: When the input "size " is 3 the return value is:  whatIsThis(array, 2) + array[2] = array[1] + array[1] + array[2] = 1+ 1 + 2 so you are wrong.

Comment: @Dr.Haimovitz with all do respect, please test something before correcting someone. You are wrong: `whatIsthis(arr, 3) = arr[2] + whatIThis(arr, 2) = arr[2] + arr[1] + whatIsThis(arr, 1) = arr[2] + arr[1] + arr[0] = 3 + 2 + 1 = 6`

Comment: Im sorry my fault i thought that the stopping condition is if p equals to 0 sorry!

Comment: `f({1,2,3},3) = 3 + f({1,2,3},2) = 3 + 2 + f({1,2,3},1) = 3 + 2 + 1 = {1,2,3}` for the original version.

Comment: thanks for your interest and replying the question.appreciate

Answer (score 1):

The function calculates the sum of the elements in the array recursively.

When the function is called the first time p=10. The part 
`return b[p-1]+ whatIsThis(b,p-1)` will take `b[9]` and call the the function with  `whatIsThis(b,9)` which will return 
`return b[8]+ whatIsThis(b,8)`... all the way upto 
`return b[1]+ whatIsThis(b,1)` which will return `b[0]`.